# Display the reason I just got an alert?

Tags: notifications, alerts

My phone makes a noise when I get a text or email.

Can it also display a line of text saying what the text or email is from? I hate having to check all my apps to see which one wants my attention.

I also want to know why it wants my attention, as in, who just texted me? Who just emailed me? what did they say?

Answer (score 3):

You should see a notification icon in the bar at the top of the screen.

Swipe down and you can click on the notification to load the application that generated it.

In addition you can install [SMS Popup](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup&feature=search_result) or something similar to display the details of the SMS on screen immediately. I haven't found anything like this for email though.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I see nothing. The small icons at top let do not even turn red...

The iPhone, when you return to if after an absence, displays a list of calls and texts received on the main screen...nothing like that for Android?

Answer (score 1):

[Voice Notify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pilot51.voicenotify&feature=search_result) may help as well. It is not necessarily practical in every situation (i.e. meetings), but can be handy at home when your phone is charging across the room and you don't want to have to get up to look at it every time it buzzes.